# add and remove the item from the array, if it exists then remove it else add. PS: its not a basic array manipulation problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

this is a json structure that i intend to create before sending to the backend an object of key value pairs
where in, the key represents the category, (lets say customer churn rate), and each category is an array, the, check marked options get added to the array of that specific category however when i click on the same checkbox again and if the item is already present in the array then remove it else add it
Note each category is an array and can have multiple items added to it.
CURRENTLY -> the items get added to its specific category but do not get removed if i click on it again. PS: i have tried splice but that didn't really work

this is the json that im mapping and rendering in my jsx ->

```
 const mainObj = {
    "Sales Performance by Product Category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic",
        "Insight 2: story content, topic",
        "Insight 3: story content, topic",
        "Insight 4: story content, topic",
        "Insight 5: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Customer Lifetime Value Analysis category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic",
        "Insight 2: story content, topic",
        "Insight 3: story content, topic",
        "Insight 4: story content, topic",
        "Insight 5: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Sales Conversion Funnel Analysis category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic",
        "Insight 2: story content, topic",
        "Insight 3: story content, topic",
        "Insight 4: story content, topic",
        "Insight 5: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Sales Forecasting and Demand Planning category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic",
        "Insight 2: story content, topic",
        "Insight 3: story content, topic",
        "Insight 4: story content, topic",
        "Insight 5: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Customer Segmentation and Targeting category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic",
        "Insight 2: story content, topic",
        "Insight 3: story content, topic",
        "Insight 4: story content, topic",
        "Insight 5: story content, topic"
    ]
}
```

THE JSX where I'm mapping through and rendering the data

```
   {Object.entries(mainObj).map(([category, stories]) => {

              return (
                <div className="bg-white rounded p-6 mb-8" key={category}>
                  <div>
                    <h1 className=' font-semibold text-base mb-4'> {category}</h1>

                    <div className=' border border-[#E5E7EB] flex flex-col rounded-md w-[36rem] min-h-[12rem] h-fit max-h-[32.6rem]'>

                      {stories.map((item, index) => {
                        return (

                          <label key={index} className="flex items-center border-b-[1px] border-[#E5E7EB] pt-[10px] pl-4 min-h-[3.2rem] max-h-[4.4rem] pb-[10px] h-fit gap-3">
                            <div className="w-4 h-4">
                              <input type="checkbox" onChange={() => handleCheckboxChange(category, item, index)} className="accent-black w-4 h-4" />
                            </div>
                            <span className="">{item}</span>
                          </label>
                        )
                      })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )
            })}
```

`const [selectedStories, setSelectedStories] = useState({});`
and this is the function which gets triggered when the user starts selecting the topics/stories that he wants,

```
  const handleCheckboxChange = (category, storyTitle) => {

    setSelectedStories((prevState) => {
      const updatedStories = { ...prevState };

      if (!updatedStories[category]) {
        updatedStories[category] = [];
      }

      if (!updatedStories[category].includes(storyTitle)) {
        updatedStories[category].push(storyTitle)


        if (!selectedCategories.includes(category)) {
          setSelectedCategories([...selectedCategories, category]);
        }

      }
      return { ...updatedStories };
    });
    console.log(selectedStories);

  };
```

assuming i choose
2 stories/topics from category one i.e Sales Performance by Product Category"
1 from category, Customer Lifetime Value Analysis
1 from category, Sales Conversion Funnel Analysis
3 from category, Sales Forecasting and Demand Planning
and 2 from, category, Customer Segmentation and Targeting

then this is what the object/ json structure  looks like before sending it the backend

```
{
    "Sales Performance by Product Category": [
        "Insight 1:  story content, topic",
        "Insight 2:  story content, topic"
    ],
    "Customer Lifetime Value Analysis": [
        "Insight 1:  story content, topic"
    ],
    "Sales Conversion Funnel Analysis": [
        "Insight 1:  story content, topic"
    ],
    "Sales Forecasting and Demand Planning": [
        "Insight 1:  story content, topic",
        "Insight 2:  story content, topic",
        "Insight 3:  story content, topic"
    ],
    "Customer Segmentation and Targeting": [
        "Insight 1:  story content, topic",
        "Insight 2:  story content, topic"
    ]
}
```

Note: the json structure should not be changed and with the current code im able to achieve a unique category and even adding tick-marked titles/stories in each categorie's array however im not able to figure out how do i remove the specific story the specic category if the user un-ticks it by clicking on it again, i.e if a story is alreay there in the array and the user has clicked on its checkbox again then remove it from the array of that specific category and if he clicks on it again and then if it doesn't exist then add it back. HENCE if its present in the array and the user clicks on it, add it , but if it exists and the user clicks on it again then remove it.

Answer (score 0):

In `setSelectedStories`, you don't seem to have logic to handle removing an item.  To me it makes sense to add an else clause on the second `if`:

```
setSelectedStories((prevState) => {
  const updatedStories = { ...prevState };

  if (!updatedStories[category]) {
    updatedStories[category] = [];
  }

  if (!updatedStories[category].includes(storyTitle)) {
    // the title did not exist in state, so add it
    updatedStories[category].push(storyTitle)


    if (!selectedCategories.includes(category)) {
      setSelectedCategories([...selectedCategories, category]);
    }

  } else {
    // the title did exist in state, so remove it
    let index = updatedStories[category].indexOf(storyTitle));
    updatedStories[category].splice(index, 1);
    // probably do something with setSelectedCategories
  }
  return { ...updatedStories };
});
```

Comment: tried your code and it works till an extent but one problem with it is even after un checking tick boxes its still stores one question from each category  even after un checking every tick box it's still stored one title from each category ->
{
    "Sales Performance by Product Category": [
        "Insight 1: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Customer Lifetime Value Analysis category": [
        "Insight 2: story content, topic"
    ],
    "Sales Conversion Funnel Analysis category": [
        "Insight 2: story content, topic"
    ],
  
}